# How do I test my actions, state and UI. I'm using context API with jest and testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have Context wrapped around my app with some state. I get access to **state** and **dispatch** in my components through my useMyState and useMyDispatch hooks (just simplifying). Then I have fat actions where the entire state management happens and my reducer is very thin. Just spreads the new payload and returns the state. My action looks like this:

```
async function myAsyncFunction(dispatch: CurrencyDispatch, state: CurrencyState, name: string) {

  const thingOne = sompute thing...
  const thingTwo = await getThing();

  dispatch({
    type: ActionTypes.SOME_ACTION,
    payload: {
      thingOne,
      thingTwo,
    },
  });
}
```

Some actions happen in apps Provider like fetching and setting some initial state before the UI shows up and I'm showing spinner. How do I test these actions and see whether global store is updated as expected?

I'm testing with `jest` and `testing-library/react`

```
test('Render with initial state', async () => {
  const {getByText, getByTestId} = render(
    <Provider>
      <MyApp/>
    </Provider>
  );

  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => getByTestId('loader'));
  expect(getByText('My title')).toBeInTheDOM();
});
```

The test fails. Here I end up with Spinner because my app that sets the initial state has not been called.

- How do I properly mock my `myAsyncFunction` in this case?
- How do I dispatch mock data?
- How do I read a new state and test if UI is updated as I expect?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that this is a proper way to mock the state but here's how I'm doing it:

> How do I properly mock my myAsyncFunction in this case?
> Use jest.mock

```
jest.mock('../api/myService', () => {
  getDataList: () => jest.fn,
}));
```

> How do I dispatch mock data?

> How do I read a new state and test if UI is updated as I expect?

Just change the store value on adhoc during test, but create a wrapper first:

**WRAPPER**

```
import MyContext, { defaultState } from './providers/mycontext';

export mockState = defaultState;

interface IMyState {
 myState: typeof defaultState.store;
}

const wrapDep = (tree: ReactNode, state?: IMyState) => {
    const mState = state?.myState ? state.myState : mockState.store;
    return (
     <MyContext.Provider value={{...mockState, store: mState}}>
        {tree}
     </MyContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**TESTING**

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    it('should display data', () => {
      const { getByText } = render(wrapDep(<MyComponent itemId={''} />, {
         myState: {
           ...mockState.store,
           items: mockItems
         }
      }));
      expect(getByText(mockItems[0])).not.toBeNull();
    });
});
```